# Why am I getting this error message from WinLess?

Tags: compiler-errors, less

I'm trying to learn Less and am currently doing an exercise in which I have to write a pretty complex bit of code in Less. I'm working from a workbook and as far as I can tell I've written the code exactly as I have been told to, but I keep getting the error:

> Parse error: Missing closing )

Here is the code, the section this error concerns is highlighted with two *'s at either side:

```
@waarde: -((38*@index)-38);
background-position: ~"@{waarde}px" 0;


.menuspan (@bgc, @col, @tshad) {
background-color: @@bgc;
color: @@col;
text-shadow: 0 0 5px @@tshad;
}

//m_item1
@bgcolor_1:     #7da315;
@color_1:       #3d4f0c;
@tshadow_1:     #99bf31;
//m_item2
@bgcolor_2:     #1e8bb4;
@color_2:       #223a44;
@tshadow_2:     #44a8d0;
//m_item3
@bgcolor_3:     #c86c1f;
@color_3:       #5a3517;
@tshadow_3:     #d28344;
//m_item4
@bgcolor_4:     #d0a525;
@color_4:       #604e18;
@tshadow_4:     #d8b54b;
//m_item5
@bgcolor_5:     #af1e83;
@color_5:       #460f35;
@tshadow_5:     #d8b54b;

.lusGuardedMixin (@index) when (@index < 0) {

@waarde: -((38*@index)-38);

**(~".m_item@{index}")** {
background-position: ~"@{waarde}px" 0px;

&:hover {
background-position: ~"@{waarde}px" -39px;
}

& span {
.menuspan(~"bgcolor_@{index}", ~"color_@{index}", ~"tshadow_@{index}")
}
}

.lusGuardedMixin(@index + 1);
}

.lusGuardedMixin (6) {}
.lusGuardedMixin (1);
```

The compiler seems to be looking for the ) too early, because it is definitely there but it's acting as though it isn't. How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have any idea what version of Less compiler is being used? As far as I know those braces, escape, quotes are not required in the recent version. And I honestly don't understand why your mixin loop is coded the way it is. It would enter the loop only when @index is less than 0 but you are using positive numbers in the call.

Comment: I downloaded it from the site today so I'm guessing it is the most recent version then :D How should I set it up then?

EDIT: please ignore the < symbol in the code. I don't know how but that is a typo. It's a > in the real code .D

Comment: In the latest version of the compiler, the code that is present in [this demo](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/xZoWMO) is all that you need. Try it out and let me know in case it works.

Comment: Thank you for that. It does seem to be working. However I have a new error. EDITT: NEVER MIND. I had forgotten to delete a piece of MY code which appeared above your code when I pasted it through. It works perfectly. Thank you so much for your time and your help :)

Comment: Honestly I have no idea. Your Less version might have something to do with it because the code I gave compiles fine in CodePen and http://lesscss.org/less-preview

Comment: Just to summarize comments above: the problem is not in WinLess, but in the code you've tried to compile (it uses the syntax deprecated three years ago, thus whatever source you copied that code snippet from is vastly outdated, consider to use some more up-to-date Less tutorial).

Comment: Yeah I get it. Sadly, I'm doing a full-time course right now and I'm kinda hamstrung into using their materials if I want to pass the course. I'll just have to tackle these problems as I come to them :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in comments, this is not a problem with either WinLess or with Less itself. The problem is with the code that you had used for compilation. It was probably taken from an outdated source that is still using old syntax (which was deprecated a few years ago) and hence the compilation error.

The following are the errors that needed to be corrected:

- The first two lines in code will produce a compilation error because `@index` variable is available only within the mixin loop and not outside of it. This is not at all required and may just have been a copy-paste error.

  ```
  @waarde: -((38*@index)-38);
  background-position: ~"@{waarde}px" 0;
  ```
- Next, the selector interpolation syntax that is used is an outdated/deprecated one. The escaping, braces and quotes are not at all required in the latest version of the compiler. Instead of this,

  ```
  (~".m_item@{index}"){...}
  ```

  just the below is enough:

  ```
  .m_item@{index} {...}
  ```
- Finally, the loop itself has an error because the guard is checking for `@index` less than 0 but the input values for the mixin is both greater than 0 and hence the mixin will never get invoked. Also, the two mixin calls at the end is not required and they can be changed into just `.lusGuardedMixin (5);`.

Making all the above mentioned changes, the code available in [this demo](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/xZoWMO) should compile fine without any errors in the latest compiler.

*(Adding my comments and demo as an answer so as to not leave the question unanswered)*